# How to solve quartic polynomial equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Can someone tell me how to solve $x^4 + 6x^2 + 5 = 0$? I know what to do when each term has an exponent one less than the previous term (e.g., $x^4 + 3x^3 + 6x^2 + 5 = 0$), but not when exponents are "skipped" like this. Ideas?

Comment: Solve for $x^2$ first. Note that our polynomial is $(x^2+1)(x^2+5)$. There are no real roots. There are $4$ complex roots.

Comment: Put $y=x^2$, which will make things clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $t=x^2$. Then we have that
$$
x^4+6x^2+5=0 \Longleftrightarrow t^2+6t+5=0 \Longleftrightarrow (t+5)(t+1)=0.
$$
Thus, $t=-5$ and $t=-1$ will be solutions. But we have to be careful because we have $t=x^2$. Thus, we really need to solve $x^2=-5$ and $x^2=-1$. Thus, the answers will be $x=\pm\sqrt{-5},\pm\sqrt{-1}$.